# Spring security usa apenas o ultimo login

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Estou criando uma aplicação simples com Spring boot 2.7.9, usando Spring security (JPA), consigo logar normalmente após verificar o usuário no BD, no entanto, quando logo com um outro usuário em uma pagina anônima ou em outro PC, ele fica com o ultimo usuário que logou para todos que estão acessando ao mesmo tempo. Alguém já passou por isso e sabe como arrumar isso?

ConfiguracaoSeguranca:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ConfiguracaoSeguranca extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
    http.addFilterBefore(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    
    http.csrf().disable();
    
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/api/usuario/token/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/auth/**").hasAuthority("Administrador")  
    .antMatchers("/usuario/**").hasAnyAuthority("Administrador","Normal")
    //.antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()   
    .and()
    
    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/error")
    .and()
    
    .formLogin(
    (form) -> form.loginPage("/login") // Page de Login
    .permitAll()
    .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
    .failureUrl("/login?error=true") // Erro de autenticação
     );  
    
    http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login"); // Ao deslogar retora para Login

}       
@Autowired
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    try {
        auth
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        
    }
    }
}
```

UserDetailsServiceImpl:

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;
    
@Override
@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Usuario usuario = usuarioRepository.findByUsername(username);
    
    if(usuario != null) {
        
        SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(usuario.getAcesso());
        
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        
        authorities.add(authority);
        
        User userSpring = new User(usuario.getUsername(), usuario.getPassword(), authorities);
        
        return userSpring;
    }       
    return null;
}
}
```

Application.properties:

```
#Configuração do BD Postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/SECURITY?currentSchema=auth
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```